# Made exact same htaccess change to allow one IP address, but it's not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just changed web hosts and I'm trying to re-apply some of the same IP address restrictions on my webhost. However, making the exact same changes does not appear to be working.

For example, I'm wanting to allow only one IP address, here's what was on my old web host:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
</IfModule>
```

with my IP address obfuscated obviously. However, when I do that on the new web server, it seems to not even allow my IP address. I'm not 100% exactly sure why this is happening if this is the exact same configuration.

For what it is worth, I'm using `VirtualHosts`, so I have configurations for the virtual hosts in /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.conf file, but nothing for mod_rewrite or anything pertaining to IP address restrictions.This change is being made in the .htaccess file in the HTML directory for the specific web host. This change is being made in the .htaccess file in the HTML directory for the specific web host.

If I simply remove those 3 lines, everything works perfectly fine, so I'm a little puzzled.

### Updated

So I tried to make adjustments by using "Require", as preferred in Apache 2.4, and it seems like I'm still getting access denied. Here's an example of my virtual host configuration file:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite
<Directory /var/www/html/mysite/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    #Require all granted

    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
      <RequireAny>
        Require ip <myip>
      </RequireAny>
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

I've tried with `IfModule` and without it, and the same goes for `RequireAny`. I tried replacing "Require all granted" with that one `Require ip <myip>` statement and still getting denied.

Comment: Can you check the Apache Version? May need Require instead. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

Comment: @JasonB hmm so I went to the configuration file for the actual site, and changed "Require all" to "Require ip <myip>", reloaded the Apache configuration, and still getting an access denied for some reason."